# How to run ps1 function from compiled python script?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to run a ps1 function from python script. It works when I run python script from cmd, but when I compile python script (with pyinstaller), it prints out every single line from ps1 function, instead of just running it.

Here's my code for python script:

```
os.system("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://example.com/script.ps1'))")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the os.system function outputs the standard output of the command to the console, which is not visible when running the compiled executable.

To execute the PowerShell script without displaying the output, you can redirect the output to a file or to the null device using the > or 2>

```
os.system("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://example.com/script.ps1')) 2> nul")
```

Comment: Like the `os.system` documentation already tells you, a much better solution is to use `subprocess`

Comment: Note that the question states, "it prints out every single line from ps1 function, instead of just running it."